# How to edit a uitextfield without deleting some characters in ios Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a textfield which shows the discount of a product.

While loading the value of text field will be `0.00`

But when the user starts typing, lets say he enter `2`, then in the textfield the decimal values `00` should go and the new value should be `0.2`

Then if he enter 5, then the new value should be `0.25`

I must also prevent the user from deleting the first two digits i.e. `0.`

If he dismiss the keyboard with no value entered, then the value must be set to default `0.00`. Its a bit tricky. How and where can I implement this?

Comment: what are you did by your own , show me what you are try ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
      if(textField.text.length && [textField.text containsString:@"."] ){
        NSArray *array=[textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        if ([[array lastObject] integerValue] == 0){
            textField.text =[[array firstObject] stringByAppendingString:@"."];
        }
    }
     return yes;
}
```

Comment: hi, it kind of works. but the issue is if I enter 2, then the value becomes `0.2`, then if I enter 5, the value should add to the text field and the value should be `0.25`. But with this code, the value becomes `0.5`

Comment: check updated answer and let me know if working or no

Comment: Yes. But a minor correction. `if ([[array lastObject] isEqualToString:@"00"]){` so that I can enter `0.02`. In your code. I can't. I'll accept the answer though :)